# Return only the row where the date in one column is closest to the date in another column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm working on a query but it's returning some duplicate values and I need to return only the row where the date in one column is closest to the date in another column.

My query looks something like this:

```
SELECT p.Id, r.ReferralDate, s.SupervisionDate
FROM person p
INNER JOIN referral r on r.PersonId = p.Id 
INNER JOIN supervision s on s.PersonId = p.Id
```

Which returns something like this:

| Id | Supervision Date | Referral Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2015-09-30 | 2015-08-30 |
| 123 | 2020-02-30 | 2015-08-30 |
| 123 | 2020-06-30 | 2015-08-30 |
| 456 | 2010-06-30 | 2010-07-30 |
| 456 | 2005-06-30 | 2010-07-30 |

How can I write a query that returns the Supervision Date that is closest to the Referral Date? So that the final output looks like this:

| Id | Supervision Date | Referral Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2015-09-30 | 2015-08-30 |
| 456 | 2010-06-30 | 2010-07-30 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two ways in this scenario to select the record that you need.

1. I prefer this way as it is very effective solution.  We get the row order by date difference and select the mini date difference. first way you can select what columns to show. This is also more generic solution.

   ```
   SELECT  A.Id
    , A.ReferalDate
    , A.Supervision 

   FROM 
   (

    SELECT 
      p.Id
      , r.ReferalDate
      , s.Supervision   
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.Id ORDER BY  DATEDIFF(DD,r.ReferalDate,s.Supervision) ASC) as [row_num]
     FROM person p
        INNER JOIN referral r 
           on r.pid = p.Id 
        INNER JOIN supervision s 
          on s.pid = p.Id
    ) AS A 
   WHERE A.row_num = 1
   ```

[image: Result]

2. this way we order by date difference and get the top 1 record.  If you add this in to CTE or Derived table, you can still return only the columns you need. This query is scenario specific as we do not consider partitions.

   ```
   SELECT top 1
       p.Id
      , r.ReferalDate
      , s.Supervision   
      ,DATEDIFF(DD,r.ReferalDate,s.Supervision) as [date dif]
   FROM person p
   INNER JOIN referral r 
       on r.pid = p.Id 
   INNER JOIN supervision s 
       on s.pid = p.Id
   ORDER BY [date dif] ASC
   ```

Both ways return the same result as our order by is placed on date difference.

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

here is one way:

```
select p.Id, r.ReferralDate, s.SupervisionDate from (
 select p.Id, r.ReferralDate, s.SupervisionDate , row_number() over (partition by id order by abs(datediff(day , ReferralDate,SupervisionDate))) rn
 from person p
 join referral r on r.PersonId = p.Id 
 join supervision s on s.PersonId = p.Id
) t
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

another way:

```sql
select ID, SUP from 
( SELECT 
   p.Id 'ID', 
   r.ReferralDate 'REF', 
   s.SupervisionDate 'SUP',
   min(julianday(s.SupervisionDate) - julianday(r.ReferralDate) ) 'diff'

FROM person p
INNER JOIN referral r on r.PersonId = p.Id 
INNER JOIN supervision s on s.PersonId = p.Id

GROUP BY p.ID
)
```

This will return ID and SupervisionDate as reqested.

Comment: Unless I'm confused, this will return 1 row in total, not 1 row per id.

Comment: @Andrew you are absolutely correct, the poster's example used only ID 123, so I did not take into consideration that there would be other IDs.  Post will be updated, my mistake. Shows how important good sample date is.

Comment: Is there an alternative to julianday()? It does not work in SQL server.

Comment: @JLo, apologies, read your question as SQLite. For MSSQL I believe you can use [DATEDIFF(day, firstdate, seconddate)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) instead of the difference between julian dates. Then just select minimum of that.

Comment: This answer is using some function julianday()  which is in SQLLIte.